# Route redirecting to main url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to understand the way angular 2 routing works. I have defined two child route paths 'movieCategory/create' and path: 'movieCategory', 
When i type http://localhost:4200/#/movieCategory it works fine and showing MovieCategory component. But when i type http://localhost:4200/#/movieCategory/create to browser , it shows CreateMovieCategory component but the url becomes  http://localhost:4200/#/movieCategory again. 
What am i doing wrong ? 
And the second question where does the # come from ?

My routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'movieCategory',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Film Kategorileri'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'movieCategory/create',
        component: CreateMovieCategory
      },
      {
        path: 'movieCategory',
        component: MovieCategory
      }

    ]
  }
];
```

I also have a button which displays the same behaviour when i click it.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" [routerLink]="['/movieCategory/create']">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
export const routeConfig:Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: FullLayoutComponent
    }

    {        
        path: 'movieCategory',
        children: [
            {
             path: 'create',
             component: CreateMovieCategory               
            }
        ]    
    }
];
```

For more info check this [LINK](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/).

If you use [PathLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles) as describe [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles) you can remove the hash in the URL.